# How to unbind/remove context menu using ContextMenu plugin by Chris Domigan in jquery?

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I am using [jQuery context menu plugin by Chris Domigan](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/) to appy a context menu.

I am registering/binding context menu like this:

```
$('#myDiv').contextMenu('myMenu', {
    bindings: {
        /* events here */
    }
}
```

Now some where in my application, I do not want this conext menu for `#myDiv`. 
So, how can I un-register/unbind/remove this context menu for `#myDiv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to use to disable contextMenu is:

```
$('#myDiv').off('contextmenu');
```

This uses jQuery's [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function, it simply removes the contextMenu event. It isn't perfect as it doesn't undo everything the plugin did but it should work for your case.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/wPhYz/